# How to capitalize each first word of string rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string:

```
test = "estrela do mar, calangute"
```

I want a string:

```
Estrela Do Mar, Calangute
```

I tried:

```
test.upcase
```

Which gave me:

```
ESTRELA DO MAR, CALANGUTE
```

And:

```
test.capitalize
```

Returned:

```
Estrela do mar, calangute
```

Answer (score 7):

try this out

```
  test = "estrela do mar, calangute"

  test.titleize

  => "Estrela Do Mar, Calangute"
```